# Can we store Sitecore item in session

Tags: sitecore

Can we store Sitecore item in session.

Below are the example. Here this item [ "/sitecore/content/Vitality/Data/my_points/mypoints" ]

I have to use in many functions because. I want to avoid to use static path so want to store this in session. Is there any way to handle this.

```cs
 Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = contextDB.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Vitality/Data/my_points/mypoints");
```

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion you should avoid storing **Sitecore** items in session. This can lead to potential memory leaks and those items will be stored for every session which is not yet expired on the server side for every new session so your application memory use might grow without any way of handling this.

In theory **Sitecore** built-in cache should work fine but if it's not enough for you may try to cache only some field values that you need to use for the item in session instead of storing the whole `Item` object. Still you need to remember that you need to handle item changes in a custom way so every time the item is changed, cached values are cleared or renewed.

Comment: Good answer and I concur. One other point to consider is that the Sitecore.Data.Items.Item class is not serializable. So if you're storing Sitecore item objects in session and attempt to serialize the session state for any reason, you will be slapped for being bad.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with [Maras Musielak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157833/maras-musielak). Storing the item in session is not the way to go. 
This actually seems like one of the few occasions where a simple static class would be useful:

```cs
static class CommonItems
{
     public static Item MyPoints
     {
         get
         {
             return Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}");
         }
     }
}
```

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = CommonItems.MyPoints;
```

On a side note, it's almost always better to instantiate an item from its GUID rather than its path as this means your code its not as dependant on the structure of the sitecore tree.

Comment: You could extend this further and have a null check and setter. Add in a publish pipeline to set the static Item back to null. Or better still, if use Glass (or another ORM) for a more strongly typed object :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others in that you should not store the item in session.  The Sitecore item cache will help you from a memory usage perspective.

TwentyGotoTen's idea of using a static getter is a good way to go to allow you to centralize your retrieval of the item so that your code doesn't have to be copy-pasted around.

Another extension to that idea is to not reference the content itself in the code, but instead load a configuration item from the content tree which can be edited to point at different content items.  In that way, your authors can change which data item is being referenced without updating the static getter.

This involves creating some sort of item in your tree to use for configurations, and having a Generic Link Field item on it that can be used to link to your my points data item.

This is a more complex solution, but allows for complete separation of the content that authors might have access to from the code.  If your myPoints information is not going to be accessed by authors, and is essentially a 'developer' item, then this extra layer of separation would not be needed.

**Example (based on TwentyGotoTen's):**

```
static class CommonItems
{
    public static Item MyPoints
    {
        get
         {
             var referenceItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{12345678-ABCD-12AB-1A1A-1234567890}");
             var myPointsField = referenceItem.Fields["myPoints"];
             if(myPointsField != null)
             {
                 LinkField linkField = (LinkField)myPointsField;
                 if(linkField.IsInternal && linkField.TargetItem != null){
                     return linkField.TargetItem;
                 }
             }

             return null;
         }
     }
}
```

}

Comment: I was going for simplicity in my answer, but if you want to do things properly this is definitely the way to go, as it decouples the referenced items from the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just from my practical experience you can save sitecore item to session if you are using InProc session. If you are using any option other than InProc, you cannot save it session as the Item class is not serializable. Had some issues with Glass mapper classes where I explicitly stored the item inside the model class and added it to session.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore itself stores specific items in static variables through its API. One example is the FieldIDs class. So yes it's totally valid to do the same in your libraries.

Drazen

Answer (score 0):

Be especially aware of load-balanced solutions. 
You might lose your session, or need to make all things stored in the session serializable.

That said, take a look at CompiledDomainModel on a neat way to handle your configuration items.